# Comma placement before and after names

Tags: commas

> Comma misuse is nothing to take lightly. It can lead to a train wreck like this:
>
> Example: **Mark Twain's book, Tom Sawyer, is a delight.**
>
> Because of the commas, that sentence states that Twain wrote only one book. In fact, he wrote more than two dozen of them.

[Source](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp)

Why is this sentence a trainwreck? What is the correct placement of commas to un-train-wreck it?

How about this?

> Mark Twain's second book, Tom Sawyer, is a delight.

Comment: The 'train wreck' is ambiguous.  The context of the sentence could easily clarify, if necessary, that Mark Twain wrote more than one book.

Comment: The opinions as to whether there should be commas above are all over the map.  To some it's clearly a parenthetical, and since (they believe that) parentheticals *must* be set aside using commas, the commas are manditory.  Others either don't view it as parenthetical or are not so anal about the use of commas.

Comment: It's not the best example. There is a difference, however, between *my brother, Jacob* and *my brother Jacob* (at least in the absence of other context). At ELL, see *[Should two nouns always be separated by a comma?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9653)*

Comment: As I noted in my answer below, the original source actually has "Tom Sawyer" italicized (essentially; it shows as non-italicized because the entire sentence is italicized), which helps to clarify the intended meaning. Your copy of that sentence here omits that important detail.

Answer (score 2):

The [source](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp) would seem to suggest that the non-train-wreck version of that sentence would be:

**Mark Twain's book *Tom Sawyer* is a delight.**

I.e., simply remove the commas, since the sentence is specifically talking about the delightful nature of *Tom Sawyer*, among Mark Twain's many books, rather than Mark Twain's one-and-only book, as is implied when commas are used.

Comment: A further ambiguity of the version with the commas, Nick Jones, is that *Tom Sawyer* as set off by commas could be a *vocative* (like *Nick Jones* in the present sentence). And do not underestimate the disambiguating value of the italics in your non–train-wreck version.

Comment: Yes, I had noted that the source had "Tom Sawyer" non-italicized in an otherwise italicized sentence, which was why my non-train-wreck version italicized it. I wasn't meaning to slip in an additional disambiguation of my own creation.