# Can you ever place a comma ᴀꜰᴛᴇʀ the word "which"?

Tags: commas, orthography, prepositional-phrases, style-manuals, parentheticals

Is there any scenario in which a comma is used **right after** the word *which*?

For example, is this sentence correctly written as is — or not?

> The sensitivity to material AAA**, which, in fact,** is sensitivity to molecular forces, decreases at lower temperatures.

I searched for my question, but could not find relevant content.

Comment: Commas are not placed with regard to particular words. The extra commas around _, in fact,_ are not needed and should be deleted: _material AAA, which in fact is sensitivity..._

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for the comment. You are right ...

Comment: It is not possible to answer comma questions that ask whether they are "correct". All we can say is that one style guide or another, or one stylist or another, does or does not recommend that they be used or omitted. Related: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/374622), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/154464), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/298559), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/121646), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/531226).

Comment: It's not uncommon for "which" to be followed by a "parenthetical" phrase.  Such phrases are typically set off by commas.